# Redis gem watch and unwatch confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

According to the redis-rb ruby gem docs;

```
redis.watch("key") do
 if redis.get("key") == "some value"
  redis.multi do |multi|
   multi.set("key", "other value")
   multi.incr("counter")
  end
 else
  redis.unwatch
 end
end
```

I have two questions about this;

1. Why is the unwatch line required? My thought is that if key == "some value", set "key" to other value and increase counter if "key" has not changed by the time EXEC is called. In my mind, the else statement never gets executed in this scenario. If you run this code without the else/unwatch, nil is returned.
2. If redis.watch "key" is entered without a block (redis.watch "key"); Why am I unable to unwatch a specific key? I get (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))??

Here is a link to the ruby gem https://github.com/redis/redis-rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Ruby nor Redis expert.

Though by reading the Redis documentation about transaction here https://redis.io/topics/transactions we learn that a watched key is unwatched in two ways : either after EXEC is used. (then the transactions completes) or either by UNWATCH.

So there is indeed a reason to use UNWATCH. If the multi block is not called then EXEC is not called either. Then the key is never flushed.

Also I think the conditionnal bit containing `redis.unwatch` can indeed happen to be called. As `redis.get("key") == "some value"` seems to be purely arbitrary and basically a code design.
It could well be `redis.get("key") > "some value"` for example.

(Also it seem having a block passed to watched does not UNWATCH the key automatically as per documentation, as the block is optionnal)

For your second question you are correct, you cannot unwatch a specific key it seems. Though `redis.unwatch` seems to work fine.

This does not seem to be a Ruby design. Watching a key is only useful in order to process an atomic transaction, there is no point in leaving watched keys behind us when transaction is either successful or aborted.

I don't see any example of using UNWATCH in the Redis documentation https://redis.io/topics/transactions but it feels natural to flush every key after the transaction block.

Comment: I am not sure if I was clear in my first question; I ran the code with "key" = "some value" and when 'else unwatch' is present, the code returns "key" = "other value" and when 'else unwatch' is not present (despite not being executed) the code returns nil. https://github.com/redis/redis-rb

Comment: That's strange as I get `redis.get 'key'` to return `"other value"` in both cases. Either with `else` `redis.unwatch` or not.

Comment: Strange indeed. I tested it just now, and it seems to work fine. Might have been a typo last night or something strange about the environment. I will look into it more but will likely award you the solution. Thanks so much for your input!